# defining I2S_resources

Tags: c, struct

i've been working with the new startKIT offered by XMOS in conjunction with their Audio Slice
I'm having a horrible time trying to define the r_i2s i2s_resources struct as defined in their i2s_master library from XsoftTIP

This is my latest code which gives me an error for the initialization of both of the arrays (data_in and data_out)

```
#include <xs1.h>
#include <i2s.h>

//XS1 Clock mapping
clock MCLK_CLK      =   XS1_CLKBLK_1;
clock BCLK_CLK     =   XS1_CLKBLK_2;

in buffered port:32 ADC_DATA0 = XS1_PORT_1K;
in buffered port:32 ADC_DATA1 = XS1_PORT_1L;

out buffered port:32 DAC_DATA0 = XS1_PORT_1G;
out buffered port:32 DAC_DATA1 = XS1_PORT_1H;

int main(void){

    //Set up I2S
    streaming chanend channel_data;

    r_i2s i2s = {MCLK_CLK, BCLK_CLK, MCLK, BCLK, LRCLK, {ADC_DATA0, ADC_DATA1}, {DAC_DATA0, DAC_DATA0}};
}
```

They define the r_i2s struct to be defined as this:

```
/** Resources for I2S_MASTER

typedef struct i2s_resources {
    clock cb1; /**< Clock block for MCK */
    clock cb2; /**< Clock block for BCK */

    in port mck; /**< Clock port for MCK */
    out buffered port:32 bck; /**< Clock port for BCK */
    out buffered port:32 wck; /**< Clock port for WCK */

    in buffered port:32 din[I2S_MASTER_NUM_PORTS_ADC]; /**< Array of I2S_MASTER_NUM_IN x 1-bit ports for audio input */
    out buffered port:32 dout[I2S_MASTER_NUM_PORTS_DAC]; /**< Array of I2S_MASTER_NUM_OUT x 1-bit ports for audio output */
} r_i2s ;
```

and I end up with an error like this:

```
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc: In function `main':
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: invalid initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: (near initialization for `i2s.cb1')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: invalid initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: (near initialization for `i2s.cb2')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: invalid initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: (near initialization for `i2s.mck')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: invalid initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: (near initialization for `i2s.bck')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: invalid initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: (near initialization for `i2s.wck')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: invalid initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: (near initialization for `i2s.din[0]')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: warning: excess elements in array initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: warning: (near initialization for `i2s.din')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: invalid initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: (near initialization for `i2s.dout[0]')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: warning: excess elements in array initializer
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: warning: (near initialization for `i2s.dout')
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:32: error: local variable `i2s' has type that contains a port
../src/Audio Slice with startKIT.xc:33: error: local variable `streChan' has type chanend
```

Now this is programmed in a variant of C called XC, which is the proprietary language of XMOS but there isn't a tag on stackoverflow for it and I don't have 1500 rep :(

Comment: Try to change global variables into defines. Your xc may not allow initializers with variables and not constants.

Comment: What is the value of I2S_MASTER_NUM_PORTS_ADC?

Comment: I2S_MASTER_NUM_PORTS_ADC is two, as is I2S_MASTER_NUM_PORTS_DAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xC, you cannot define local variables that contain ports or clocks. So you have to define the r_i2s structure as a global.

```
r_i2s i2s = {MCLK_CLK, BCLK_CLK, MCLK, BCLK, LRCLK, {ADC_DATA0, ADC_DATA1}, {DAC_DATA0, DAC_DATA0}};

int main(void){

    //Set up I2S
    streaming chanend channel_data;

}
```